# How to add a greek character in png file created by gnuplot

Tags: fonts, gnuplot, freebsd

I am using a commercial sever with FreeBSD system without root account. I install gnuplot with my account. But, I can not set up fonts. So, I copy the fonts files in my home directory such as ~/usr/fonts

Then, I use followed scripts in my gnuplot files:

```
set term png enhanced font '/home/Tom/usr/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/verdana.ttf'
set out 'xrd.png'
set xlabel '2 {/Symbol q}'; 
set ylabel 'Count'; 
set xrange [:];
set yrange [:];
unset key;
set border lw 1;
plot './data.txt' using 1:2 with l linetype 1 linewidth 1;
set term xterm;
set out ;
```

However, I get the following errors when I run my scripts:

```
gdImageStringFT: Could not find/open font while printing string q with font Symbol
gdImageStringFT: Could not find/open font while printing string q with font Symbol
```

This might be because the font 'verdana.ttf' that I am using is not correct. 
But, I can use this font on my own PC with a Debian system.

Comment: What versions of gnuplot and libgd do you use? What do you mean by 'the font is not correct'?

Comment: I am using gnuplot 4.6. Unfortunately, I do not know my libgd version.  Because I do not have a root account, I can not set up gnuplot well. There is no manual and help fine in my gnuplot. When I get the error message, there is no characters in my PNG figure created by gnuplot. so, I think the font that  am using is wrong.

Comment: What permissions does `verdana.ttf` have? When you type `ll` in the terminal in the directory where the file is, what does the first column say? (something like `-rw-r--r--`)

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `/Symbol`. That will not use the Verdana font.

According to [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/verdana/list.htm), the Verdana font includes greek letters.

Use UTF-8 encoding by adding `set encoding utf8` to your gnuplot file. Then insert the unicode symbol (according to [this page](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl): θ, greek small letter theta, U+03B8) into the label string using your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "/Symbol" . Simply add to your file the line  "set encoding utf8"
At least, it works with arial font.

Answer (score 0):

## The plot definition file itself needs to be encoded in UTF-8.

Here are all prerequisites for printing UTF-8 characters with `gnuplot`:

- The file needs to contain a line `set encoding utf8`
- The option `enhanced` must be available and set for the chosen terminal type: `set terminal … enhanced …`
- The **glyph** of the UTF-8 character must be **available in the chosen font.**
- The **plot definition file** itself needs to be **encoded in UTF-8.**

Failing to observe the last point, results in the following `gnuplot` error:

```
Unable to convert "…�…": the sequence is invalid in the current charset (UTF-8),
falling back to iso_8859_1
```

This situation may occur **when transferring plot files from Microsoft Windows™ to GNU/Linux.**

The character encoding of the plot definition file can be checked with the following GNU/Linux command:

```
$ file -bi bad.plt
text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

To correct the character encoding of the plot definition file, use this command:

```
$ iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 -o good.plt bad.plt
```