# Insertion of Greek letters in a graph legend using GNUplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to incorporate greek symbols into my graph using following code, but keep getting similar error twice.

warning: enhanced text mode parser - ignoring spurious }

warning: enhanced text mode parser - ignoring spurious }

```
reset

# svg
#set terminal svg size 410,250 fname "Times New Roman" \

set terminal svg size 410,250, enhanced fname 'Times New Roman' \

fsize "12" rounded dashed
set output "data1.svg"

set tics nomirror

# color definitions
set style line 1 lc rgb "#8b1a0e" pt 1 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 # --- red
set style line 2 lc rgb "#5e9c36" pt 2 ps 1 lt 2 lw 2 # --- green

set key bottom right

plot "abc.htm" using 1:2 title "N('\alpha', T)" w lp ls 1, \
 "abc.htm" using 1:3 title "N(\beta, T)" w lp ls 5
```

PS: The code was running fine until I enabled enhanced mode of svg terminal, as I needed it for inserting greek letters in my graph legends. I am using version 4.6, patch level 5. Can any one help me out?

Comment: I have no experience with this terminal, but you probably need to escape the backslashes: `... title "N('\\alpha',T)" ...`, etc. Add more backslashes if it doesn't work with just two.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks. I tried it, but it didn't worked. Though error is gone, but still unable to get greek letter and getting \alpha instead. I want to insert a high quality graph in latex document. What I am doing is, plotting graph using GNUplot, then saving svg file. Next, I convert svg file into pdf and then insert that into latex file.

Comment: If you want to use this in latex then the most obvious way to do it is by using the epslatex terminal and using latex syntax in your gnuplot code. Using single quotes you don't have to escape backslashes. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253276/gnuplot-is-there-a-way-to-add-small-gif-icon-on-the-plot/24257654#24257654

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/18753222/2604213, http://stackoverflow.com/q/19141767/2604213, or http://stackoverflow.com/q/24648086/2604213 just to mention a few possible duplicates ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to solve this problem. The Greek letters can be inserted in SVG file using following path in the Inkscape:

Go to **Text** drop down menu and then click on **Glyphs**. Next, select font family such as **Times New Roman**. After that select **Greek** from script and **all** from Range options, respectively. Then Greek letters could easily be inserted in the Graph.

Comment: Have you tried a least using utf8 as encoding and directly inserting the `α`?

Answer (score 5):

The correct way is to

1. use `enhanced` option of the terminal (you did)
2. wite `{/Symbol a}` for an alpha.

Search for symbols + gnuplot on the web, you'll find lists like http://mathewpeet.org/lists/symbols/ with codes understood by gnuplot!

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper encoding (UTF-8) and insert the characters directly:

```
reset
set encoding utf8
set terminal svg size 410,250 enhanced fname 'Times New Roman' fsize "12" rounded dashed standalone
set output "data1.svg"

set linetype 1 lc rgb "#8b1a0e" lw 2
set linetype 2 lc rgb "#5e9c36" lw 2

set key bottom right
set style function linespoints
set samples 11
plot x title "N(α, T)", 2*x title "N(β, T)"
```

[image]

Comment: most useful answer for Greeks :)

Answer (score 1):

1. choose font 'Symbol'
2. choose corresponding English alphabet for Greek letter, eg. i have chosen      'c' for 'chi', below is the link for other characters.
   http://folk.uio.no/hpl/scripting/doc/gnuplot/Kawano/label-e.html
3. fontsize can be changed easily.

eg...

set ylabel "c" font "Symbol,14"

will produce greek letter 'Chi'.

Comment: I tested this for svg output and it did not work.  Did you test it with svg?